# Nested trial and error in if-else condition

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

Using Rails 3.2, I have the following:

```
g = Geocoder.search(address)

# if no address found, geocode with latitude and longitude
if g.empty?
  g = Geocoder.search(latitude, longitude)
  if g.empty?
    log.info "Geocode failed for #{latitude}, #{longitude}"
  end
else
  ---save---
end
```

If the first geocoding with address fails, it will try latitude and longitude. If still fails, then it logs error, else it will save.

Is this a good way to write this code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some notes:

- `g`: use meaningful names.
- Don't mix code with parentheses and without.
- Check the pattern [Object#presence](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-presence).
- `# if no address found, ...`: declarative code makes this kind of comments unnecessary.

I'd write:

```
results = Geocoder.search(address).presence || Geocoder.search(latitude, longitude)
if results.present?
  # save
else
  log.info("Geocode failed for addr='#{search}' and coords=#{latitude}/#{longitude}")
end
```

Answer (score 4):

Nesting your `if`s is unnecessary, and flatting them will look better:

```
g = Geocoder.search(address)

# if no address found, geocode with latitude and longitude
if g.empty?
  g = Geocoder.search(latitude, longitude)
end

if g.empty?
    log.info "Geocode failed for #{latitude}, #{longitude}"
  end
else
  ---save---
end
```

You can even go one-liners to make the code look more succinct:

```
g = Geocoder.search(address)

# if no address found, geocode with latitude and longitude
g = Geocoder.search(latitude, longitude) if g.empty?

log.info "Geocode failed for #{latitude}, #{longitude}" && return if g.empty?

---save---
```

Comment: Ha! Your first answer was what I had before refactoring!

Comment: Nested ifs are considered [a smell](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ArrowAntiPattern), just imagine how your code look if had two more fallbacks - each fallback will nest another if, and it would be hard to read the flow of the code - does it save? does it log?